# How to mosh into a host located in LAN?

Tags: ssh, reverse-proxy, mosh

I want to `mosh` into computer A from C, possibly via the relay computer B:

A) the computer I want to connect to, sitting behind LAN 1, with no static public IP

B) a relay computer, with static public IP

C) my laptop, sitting behind LAN 2 (!= LAN 1), with no static public IP

How can I do this? I can `ssh` into A from C via `ngrok`, but ssh is flaky.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing and running an `ssh` or `vpn tunnel` on `computer A`. It might be slow, but that's probably your best bet without port forwarding. You can use some services such as `portmap.io` or `serveo.net` to map/open up ports and establish the ssh/vpn tunnel from `computer A` to their server. Any outside computer can then access `computer A` by ssh-ing the server IP and the port they assign you. As for `ngrok`, your assigned port number can change after a reboot, so you possibly wouldn't be able to ssh `computer A`. This could be a deal breaker, even if speeds and latency are noticeably faster (although still very slow compared to port forwarding).

Answer (score 0):

Put Radmin Server on computer A and set it up. Then put Radmin Viewer on your remote connection. Use SSH to make the connection and then Radmin Viewer to see Computer A. I use VPN instead of SSH but it works just great. You may need to change your Computer A LAN system external IP address occasionally but you should be able to go several months at a stretch. I use this setup a lot.